# How to register plugins using GeneratedPluginRegistrant

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

How do i register all my plugins when presenting a view controller with implicit engine?

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen#alternatively---create-a-flutterviewcontroller-with-an-implicit-flutterengine

Answer (score 2):

When you create new project in Flutter it already ships with code the registers the plugin. Check if you have following;

#### Android

In your Android project find **MainActivity.kt**.

> **Important:** Notice that `FlutterActivity` exist in both `io.flutter.embedding.android` and `io.flutter.app` but first one automatically registers all the plugins.

```
package com.example.myapp

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

// do not import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity instead


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
}
```

#### iOS

In your iOS project find **AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FlutterPluginRegistrant

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  lazy var flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(name: "my flutter engine")

  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self.flutterEngine)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

P.S. Make sure you update the Flutter version to get most of it.
[iOS reference](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/add-flutter-screen?tab=engine-uikit-swift-tab)