# How to reregister flutter plugins in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I need to register all the flutter plugins (again) in a plugin I'm developing.

The flutter does this by itself in app launch with this code :

```
// your_project/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
```

But how can I do that again by in another swift file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571029/how-to-register-plugins-using-generatedpluginregistrant check this answer!

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What underlying problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Mdomerarafat That's not what I need. It just shows the path of that file I mentioned in my question.
I want to call that method in another file.

Comment: @RichardHeap Good question!
Somewhere and in some code, I reassign the rootViewController with FlutterViewController, and after that, all the Flutter plugins are not available and need to register again.